# full text indexing only returns 2 rows

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing, mysql5

I have a table for food and hotels
like

```
CREATE TABLE `food_master` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `caption` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `category` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `subcategory` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `hotel` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `description` text,
  `status` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `created_date` date default NULL,
  `modified_date` date default NULL,
  `chosen_mark` varchar(10) default 'no',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`,`caption`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And I have data in it. I use full text indexing in this table. I use the query

```
SELECT * FROM food_master am 
WHERE MATCH(description, caption) AGAINST ('Chicken')
```

This query works fine when i have 2 'Chicken' in the field 'caption'. but when i put third one it doesnt return a row.

Comment: can you paste few table data because it even doesnt select even a  single row;   [`see here`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09d45/1)

Comment: I made basic table: Please see here : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f664e/2

Comment: sorry, i have used jfiddle to show the table content http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/t9pZU/

Comment: Please  use sql fiddle please suggested on earlier comment.

Comment: sir can u please use this query in yourown database "SELECT * FROM food_master am WHERE MATCH(description, caption) AGAINST ('Chicken ')
". I will upload the data after creating sql fiddle

Comment: I did do. but it returns `0 rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with [`IN BOOLEAN MODE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) as

> MySQL can perform boolean full-text searches using the IN BOOLEAN MODE
>   modifier. With this modifier, certain characters have special meaning
>   at the beginning or end of words in the search string.

```
SELECT * FROM food_master 
WHERE MATCH(description, caption) AGAINST ('Chicken' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

[`Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/629099/1)